# In Google Analytics, how to set view filters for tracking subdirectories?

Tags: google-analytics, subdirectory

How to set view filters for tracking subdirectories like:

```
http://www.example.com/en/us/?sc_lang=en

http://www.example.com/en/us/?sc_lang=de-EU

http://www.example.com/en/us/?sc_lang=fr-EU
```

I'm thinking of the filter as:

Predefined --> Include only --> traffic to the subdirectories --> that contain

```
/?sc_lang=de-EU
```

and then the same thing with a new view with another subdirectory filter as:

Predefined --> Include only --> traffic to the subdirectories --> that contain

```
/?sc_lang=fr-EU
```

Is this the right method or there is any other way?

Comment: This seems to be less about subdirectories and more about language parameters.

Comment: I'm not sure why your URL would have both `en/us` and `de-EU` in it at the same time.  What is on your page when the user is requesting content for both English US and German EU?